# Can I stop my detailLabel from resizing when I set UITableviewCellAccessoryCheck?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have several `UITableViewCells` which are used to choose a setting. Touching one checks it and un-checks the previously checked cell (if any). I am using the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` cell style and have about a paragraph of text in each `detailLabel`. When I set the accessory to `UITableviewCellAccessoryCheck` my `detailLabel` resizes, moving the text in a visually unappealing way. I want the detailLabel text to retain its position regardless of whether it is checked or not.

I thought I might be able to get the width of the checked accessory view and pre-emptively shrink the detailLabel width. Is this the correct way to do it?

Must I wait until the cells are about to appear or can I do it as they are created in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`?

Do I have to set the detailLabel's resize mask differently?

Answer (score 0):

set the detailTextLabel's adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property to NO.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
```

Comment: The problem isn't that the font is resizing. The problem is that when I add the checkbox accessory, the detailLabel's width shrinks to accommodate it, which causes my text to wrap differently.